# Drawing NSControl when the windows is key or not

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscontrol

I have a NSControl subview and I want to change the drawing when the control is not on a keyWindow. The problem is that I don't see any property that reflects that state (tried `enabled` property but that was not it).

In simple terms, can I differentiate between these two states?

[image: disabled][image: enabled]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSWindow's `keyWindow` property, and if you want to check to see if your control is the first responder for keyboard events also test `[[self window] firstResponder] == self`. I don't believe `keyWindow` supports KVO, but there is a `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` and `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` you can listen for. For instance,

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;
{
    if ( self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect] )
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(display) name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(display) name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)aRect;
{
    if ( [[self window] isKeyWindow] )
    {
    // one way...
    }
    else
    {
    // another way!
    }
}

- (void)dealloc;
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification object:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I decided to add start to look for notification in `viewDidMoveToWindow` and remove it in `viewWillMoveToWindow:`, to avoid notification of every window in the application. (Still seems strange to need to to register for a notification for that simple task... A little hole in a great framework.)